# OS Credential Dumping

Tags: windows, operating-system

Seen that OS credential dumping in one of Windows 2022 build workstation, when office application is attempt to run, Microsoft Edge WebView2 (MSEdgeWebView2.exe) is accessing LSASS memory.
Tried a lot to identify what exact problem is occured for that. Can anyone help me??

During that incident , sysmon was not enabled. After the incident, installed sysmon but didn’t able to find any.

Comment: relax, take a deep breath and calmly write down what happened so others might understand what went wrong and help you out, not going to downvote as that happens to much here in my opinion, just better explain what happened to you, also this is stack overflow its for developers, it does not look like a typical coding question have you seen servervault another stack alike site ?. its a bit more aimed towards administrators, maybe there is something for power users as well.

Comment: Hi peter Bhai, sorry that my question is little bit confusing for others. I will elaborate more about that very soon.